# Htaccess redirect by mask

Tags: .htaccess

Please help me to write htaccess to redirect from http://mysite.com/www.anyword.txt to http://mysite.com/anyword.txt. How could I do it? anyword is a variable, I have few files with such mask.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: (as per @anubhava's comment below)**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^www\.([^.]+\.txt)/?$ /$1 [R,L,NC]
```

If it works, change the `R` flag to `R=301` - you should never use the latter for testing if your server is live.

Comment: RewriteCond should be removed and wouldn't `RewriteRule ^www\.([^.]+\.txt)/?$ /$1 [R,L,NC]` be better?